# Php string + XPath variable results in 0?

Tags: php, variables, xpath, domdocument

Iam new to xpath. I got a url using curl and domdocument but the problem is that the link is formated in this way: /bookstore/book.php
So then I wanna echo it to my own href link, it doesnot work ofcourse. The awnser would be to make a variable thats contains both the www.hello.com and the link I got from domdocument.

Here is my line of code:

$link = $linkquery->item(2)->nodeValue;

But if I do this it just gives me an 0

$url = "http://www.hello.com" + $link;

Any ideas? I guess I have missed something basic.

Regards

EDIT

Thanks for the help, the awnser was $url = "http://www.hello.com$link";

Comment: Please add your XML and the XPath expression to your question. And you should use `$xpath->evaluate('string(//nodename[3])')`, not `$xpath->query('//nodename')->item(2)->nodeValue;`

Comment: oh okey! thanks I will fix that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the string concatenation operator in PHP the dot operator `.`? So you want `$url = "http://www.hello.com" . $link;` or simply `$url = "http://www.hello.com$link";`.